# Can't install tkinter on python3 in Linux Deepin

Tags: linux, tkinter, python-3.9

I've been trying to install tkinter with python3 in Linux to complete working on my project that I started on Windows.

I've seen many posts on askubuntu and superuser , have tried many commands but VS Code still give me an error saying :

from tkinter import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/tkinter/**init**.py", line 37, in 
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'from tkinter import *

The last command that I've tried is :
`sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

After executing it, I thought tkinter has been installed successfully as the  linux terminal didn't throw an error, the last line said : Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...

So then I reopened VSC, executed the code but nothing has changed!

### NOTE :

My current python interpreter in VS Code is python 3.9.1 64 bit

Comment: Do you have a graphical interface on your computer?

Comment: @TheLizzard yes

Comment: Did you compile Python 3.9 yourself? As the error shows that the python modules are installed inside `/usr/local/lib/python3.9`.  Normally system package will install into `/usr/lib/python3.9` instead.

Comment: Does you linux terminal use the same python version as VS Code ?

Comment: @Philippe I don't know

Comment: @acw1668 what do you mean ?

Comment: Type in terminal : `python -V`

Comment: @Philippe , it says python 2.7.16, though I have python 3.9 installed